# How to get location using external pseudo ranges in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have calculated pseudo ranges from the raw GPS data in `Android`. Now, after some operations on the pseudo ranges, I have to give back the pseudo ranges to the `API` to get back the `Location` object which has latitude and longitude. How can I do that?